# Angular2 Get SharePoint list data via REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint, angular, typescript

I am trying to build a SharePoint app (add-in) with angular2 and Typescript to retrieve list data from host web via REST. I can do it in angular1 with $http.get, but in angular2, http.get returns me error (Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference)

```
var spListUrl = appweburl + 
                "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Anno‌​uncements')/items?@t‌​arget='" + 
                hostweburl + "'"; 
let results = this.http.get(spListUrl); 
.toPromise() .then(this.SayHello) .catch(this.handleError);
```

The Sayhello function was not executed, the browser console shows the error

I suspect that it may related to the authentication, does anyone has any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. please provide some code you have already tried.

Comment: var spListUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";


   let results = this.http.get(spListUrl);
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.SayHello)
            .catch(this.handleError);

The Sayhello function was not executed, the browser console shows the error